# Oracle - Select the latest distinct record from table

Tags: oracle, distinct

In theory this seems easy but I just can't get my head around this...

Here's my table info and data

```
ID    Heading    Date         Row_Num
 1       Test    12-MAR-12          1
 1      Test2    13-MAR-12          2
 2      Test3    13-MAR-12          3
```

And here's my query

```
select * from 
table1 
where date <= :date 
order by date desc
```

`:date` being `14-MAR-12` for instance

This obviously produces all three results but what I want to achieve from this query is the following data

```
ID    Heading    Date         Row_Num
 1      Test2    13-MAR-12          2
 2      Test3    13-MAR-12          3
```

So I added in a `distinct` but this doesn't work as expected as I have to group by each column and by doing that it produces 3 results still.

Any ideas on how I can accomplish the result i'm after?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

You'll need to use an analytic function.  The row_number function should do the trick.

```
select *
from
(
    select 
        id,
        heading,
        date,
        row_number() over ( partition by id order by heading desc nulls last ) r
    from table1
)
where r = 1
```

Analytic functions can be used to perform analysis and grouping of rows within a result set.  In the example above, the inner-select queries table1 as usual.  The row_number() function will compare each row with other returned rows (using the aggregate provided in the partition statement) to produce a number.  In this case, we are grouping by ID and ordering by heading descending.  The outer-select has a where clause that filters out rows that don't have a row_number of 1.  Run just the inner-select to see how the whole thing works.

Comment: Is `ROW_NUMBER() OVER (PARTITION BY ID ORDER BY HEADING DESC)` doable in Oracle? Simple question. =)

Comment: Yes, this is only available in Oracle.  There might be equivalents on other DBMS's, but the syntax I gave you is Oracle.

Comment: @WillMarcouiller: If I'm not mistaken, Oracle was the first DBMS to support this. It's been available since Version 7

Comment: Great, thanks for informing me! I knew about `ROW_NUMBER()`, but not of `OVER (PARTITION...)` part.

Answer (score 3):

If you just want the row with the latest `DT` for each `ID`, you would want something like

```
SELECT id,
       heading,
       dt
  FROM (SELECT id,
               heading,
               dt,
               ROW_NUMBER() OVER (PARTITION BY id
                                      ORDER BY dt desc) rnk
          FROM table1)
 WHERE rnk = 1
```

If ties are possible (two rows with the same `ID` and `DT`, you may want to add something else to the `ORDER BY` in the analytic function that breaks the tie deterministically rather than letting Oracle break it arbitrarily.

Answer (score 1):

I could be misunderstanding what you want to achieve, but I think you can do it with a group by and a subquery, as follows:

```
SELECT * 
FROM table1 
WHERE ID||date IN 
  (SELECT ID||MAX(date)
  FROM table1 
  WHERE date <= to_date('14-mar-12', 'DD-mon-YY') 
  GROUP BY ID
  );
```

This will give you one row per ID and Date, as long as there are not multiple rows with the same ID and same date.

Comment: I would definitely change this to `WHERE ID, date IN (SELECT ID, MAX(date)...` rather than concatenating the values. The main reason why the other answers are preferable is that they only require one table scan, whereas this requires 2.

Comment: But `WHERE ID, date IN (SELECT ID, MAX(date)...` does not work, it returns "ORA-00920: invalid relational operator". I would like to be able to do this without concatenating the values, so if you know how please let me know.

Comment: Sorry @Jake, I copied and pasted, it's `where (id, date) in ( select ...`.